# Rails find all records with an association under certain conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having trouble finding the solution to this. 
I have one model called Users which has a has_many association with the model SalaryReport. The user has to report their salary once a month, if not a reminder is to be sent out. My problem is finding the users that have not reported their salary. I can't figure out the best way to do this.

I have tried a few different approaches but nothing that has worked yet. Has anyone got any ideas?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you post the few approaches you've tried to give more accurate answer?

Answer (score 0):

In your User model,

```rb
def self.no_salary_report
  User.all.select {|u| u.salary_reports.empty? }
end
```

To call it, `User.no_salary_report`

This will get you all the users without any `salary_reports`. I don't exactly know your model names, so this is best I can do.

---

edit 1: For time range you additionally asked

```rb
def self.no_salary_reports_between(start_date, end_date)
  User.all.select do |u| 
    u.salary_reports.select do |s|
      (start_date < s.created_at) && (end_date > s.created_at)
    end.empty?
  end
end
```

Note that `start_date` and `end_date` arguments you give to this method must be `DateTime` object to work correctly compare the value to the `created_at` values of `salary_reports`.

Comment: Wouldn't this be better as a scope?

Comment: Hi, yes that works! Is it possible to get a date range in there so i can find which periods are missing?

Comment: For example if user has sent in report for February but not January

Comment: Matt, good call on scope. Yes, this would be a good example where you could use scope as well.

Answer (score 0):

look for Users that have the last reportet salary report befor the delimiting date:

```
Users.select('users.*, max(salary_reports.report_date) report_date').joins(:salary_reports).group(:id).having('max(salary_report.report_date)<?',limiting_date)
```